# Excel - search keyword in TXT file and write line where keyword is found to an excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to search with a keyword in a TXT file and write the line where keyword is found to an excel cell.

I have a piece of VBA code that works, but it only writes the keyword + the characters i give extra to it.
So i'll exacly have to know how many characters there are after the keyword.

My question is can someone help me with the code that it can write the complete line.. so to end of line..

I'll need:

- The function open file
- Easy add keywords
- Easy add Cell where keyword is placed

Thanks!!

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String
Dim text As String
Dim textLine As String

Dim S_Name As Integer

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textLine
    text = text & textLine
Loop

Close #1

S_Name = InStr(text, "keyword1")

Range("A10").Value = Mid(textLine, S_Name + 0, 30)

'save sheet to txt file
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="c:" & "keyword_file " + Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") _
& ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your `text` contain `vbNewLine`?

Comment: Hi, Mehdi.. good question.. How can i check this?

Comment: Actually, `text` containing `vbNewLine` affects your solution. If it doesn't include `vbNewLine` then the answer by Domenic is correct. While if it does the solution is different. You must know it based on your assumption or based on where `text` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

When looping through each line, test the line for the keyword, and only assign your variable `text` the line that meets the criteria, and then exit the loop immediately...

```
Open myFile For Input As #1

text = ""
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textLine
    If InStr(1, textLine, "keyword1") > 0 Then
        text = textLine
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

Close #1

Range("A10").Value = text
```

When a line feed (`chr(10`) or `vbLf`) is used to mark the end of the line, the FileSystemObject can be used instead...

```
'
'
'

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oTS As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oTS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(myFile)

text = ""
Do Until oTS.AtEndOfStream
    textLine = oTS.ReadLine
    If InStr(1, textLine, "keyword1") > 0 Then
        text = textLine
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

oTS.Close

Range("A10").Value = text

'etc
'
'

Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oTS = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi Domenic, thanks for your reply.. your code still enters the comlete file in cell A10. i would like to put the complete line where the keyword is found, entered in cell A10.

Comment: Dominic, i didn't get your code to work, but in the meanwhile have a other script working... Thank you for your help.


For Each Line In Split(text, vbLf)
test = InStr(Line, Search)
If test > 0 Then
    found = Mid(Line, test, Len(Line))
End If
Next Line

FindValue = found
End Function